# PyCharm typing warning with chained comparison

Tags: python, pycharm, typing

With the following code snippet in PyCharm:

```
print(1.0 < 2.0 < 3.0)
```

I received the following warning over the `3.0`:

> Expected type `int`, got `float` instead.

Why the expected type given by PyCharm is `int`? Is that a typing error from PyCharm or is it something fundamental about the chain comparison?

The following code do not raise any PyCharm warning:

```
print(1.0 < 2.0 < 3)
print(1.0 < 2 < 3)
```

Comment: This sounds like a PyCharm bug you could ask more about on the PyCharm bug tracker over at  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ .

Comment: @AKX, it looks like it was a known issue that was fix in 2017: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22763

I'll try to send an issues!

Answer (score 3):

I found the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22763) in the PyCharm bug tracker thanks to @AKX. It should be fix by now, I'll update my PyCharm version to 2018.

Follow-up: It's fixed in 2018.